# Why do I have a line break?

Tags: c++, string, loops, do-while, erase

there is a problem with the code. Displays an error *"std::out_of_range at memory location"*. during debugging.
The task of the code is to find all the letters "A" in the text and delete them.
**С++ code:
**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string a;
    getline(cin, a);
    int n = 0;
    do {
        n = a.find('a',1);
        cout << n;
        a.erase(n, 0);
        cout << a;
    } while (n != -1);
    cout << a;
}
```

I tried to change int to double, but the program does not work correctly. However, the error disappears

Comment: you should check the return value of find before erasing to make sure it is not std::string::npos

Comment: The documentation for [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) says *"Exceptions: std::out_of_range if index > size()."* Also, `erase(n, 0)` would erase 0 characters anyway.

Comment: _"The task of the code is to find all the letters "A" in the text and delete them_" - then why are you searching for `a` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this do-while loop

```
do {
    n = a.find('a',1);
    cout << n;
    a.erase(n, 0);
    cout << a;
} while (n != -1);
```

The first one is that you are starting to search the letter 'a' starting from the position 1 instead of the position 0.

The second one is that if the letter 'a' is not found then n is equal to std::string::npos and you are using this value in the call of erase. You need to check that n is not equal to std::string::npos before calling the member function erase.

And the call of erase in any case is incorrect.

Instead of the do-while loop it is better to use the for loop. For example

```
for ( std::string::size_type n; ( n = a.find( 'a' ) ) != std::string::npos; )
{ 
    std::cout << n;
    a.erase(n, 1 );
    std::cout << a << '\n';
}
```

Also you should declare the variable n as having the type std::string::size_type.

And as `@Ted Lyngmo` wrote in a comment if your compiler supports C++ 20 then you can use standard C++ function `erase` defined for standard containers like

```
std::erase( a, 'a' );
```

to remove all occurrences of the letter `'a'` in the string.